# Problem with \newdimen and \widthof

Tags: enumitem, calc

I have a problem with the following code under TexLive 2018:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}

\newdimen\lblwidth\lblwidth=\widthof{8.88.\ }

\newlength{\testb}
\setlength{\testb}{\widthof{8.88.\ }}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Exercises}

\begin{enumerate}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=\widthof{8.88.\ },label=\textbf{\thechapter.\arabic*.},leftmargin=!,ref=\thechapter.\arabic*]
\item Hallo
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The `\newdimen` produces an error on my system while the `\setlength` doesn't:

Part of logfile:

```
\lblwidth=\dimen106

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \widthof 
l.7 \newdimen\lblwidth\lblwidth=\widthof
                                        {8.88.\ }
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \widthof 
l.7 \newdimen\lblwidth\lblwidth=\widthof
                                        {8.88.\ }
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)


! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.7 \newdimen\lblwidth\lblwidth=\widthof{8
                                          .88.\ }
You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

\testb=\skip47
(./widthof.aux)
```

Changing `\newdimen` to `\newskip` doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\settowidth{\lblwidth}{8.88.\ }` has the correct LaTeX syntax and doesn't even require `calc`.

If you insist in using `calc`, you *must* use `\setlength`:

```
\setlength{\lblwidth}{\widthof{8.88.\ }}
```

Why is this? The primitive assignment `\lblwidth=` *requires* a legal dimension after the `=`, which `\widthof` isn't.

By the way, the meaning of `\widthof` is `\ignorespaces` and only in legal `calc` expressions it becomes really useful. The `calc` package modifies `\setlength` so that it can understand `calc` expressions. The primitive assignment cannot be handled this way.

Comment: I never thought of that. BTW, I'm reading your Italian book with the aid of our Italian housemaid